# "Too many open files" - can't remove a directory

Tags: android, linux

I've created a large tree of empty directories in an Android emulator, around 1024.

[image]

Now whenever I try to remove it with `rm -rf 1/` I get a "Too many open files" error. How can I remove it?

Comment: did you try `rm -rf  1/ --no-preserve-root`

Comment: @MinhBui Same thing, "rm failed for 1/, Too many open files"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Please try to use ulimit to set the open file handle as 4000 or more, you can use "ulimit -a" to show the current limitation of open files.
2. Please remove the deepest folder first, then rm them one by one

Comment: What worked is ulimit -n 4096 followed by find /1 -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;